# Nesting IIF and ISNULL to return last record

Tags: sql, ms-access, relational-database

I am trying to get this query for the history of a device to fill the location id of that device with its last recorded location and I'm having trouble figuring out how to make it work out that way.

**Initial Result**
[image: Current result after sub-query added]

**Desired Result**
[image: Desired Result]

The idea is that if there is no record of an install or removal the location is the same as it was in the last record for that device. The screen shots above are from before attempting to make this happen.

```
SELECT 
    ns.online, 
    n.[node serial number], 
    ns.gateway, 
    ns.[date verified], 
    nls.[location id],
    IIF (ISNULL(nls.[location id]),"null",nls.[location id]) AS [location status],
    nls.[install/remove], 
    nls.[date of action], 
    tbm.[TBM-R], 
    tbm.[TBM-L],
    ns.notes
FROM 
    (
        (nodes AS n INNER JOIN 
        [node status] AS ns ON n.nodeid = ns.[node serial]) LEFT JOIN 
        [node location status] AS nls ON (ns.[node serial] = nls.[node serial number]) AND 
        (ns.[date verified] = nls.[date of action])) LEFT JOIN 
        [TBM Station] AS tbm ON ns.[Date Verified] = tbm.[Date Reported]
WHERE 
    n.[node serial number]=[Enter node serial number]
ORDER BY 
    [date verified] DESC
```

**Current Result**
[image]

So as you can see I've managed to insert "null" into the blank cell, which is a step forward, but I am stuck trying to figure out how to get it to instead display the last recorded location id.

The 12 and 13 refer to the record id of the proper location id in the locations table (not directly referenced in the query but referenced by the `[node location status]` table via drop down). I'm not sure why it does this and it will need to be addressed, but at least I am seeing the empty cell populated at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by restructuring my data to make connecting it much simpler. I realized that `[Node Location Status]` and `[Node Status]` did not have to separate tables. After doing this the following query was able to display the location status the way I wanted it to.

```
    [Node Status].Online, 
    [Node Status].[Not in Service], 
    Nodes.[Node Serial Number], 
    [Node Status].Gateway, 
    [Gateway Status].Online, 
    [Node Status].[Location Status], 
    [Node Status].[Install/Remove], 
    [Node Status].[Date Verified], 
    [TBM Station].[TBM-L], 
    ([TBM Station].[TBM-L])-(Locations.Station) AS [TBM L], 
    ([TBM Station].[TBM-R])-(Locations.Station) AS [TBM R], 
    [Node Status].Notes
FROM 
    Locations RIGHT JOIN 
    (((Nodes INNER JOIN [Node Status] ON Nodes.NodeID = [Node Status].[Node Serial]) INNER JOIN 
    [TBM Station] ON [Node Status].[Date Verified] = [TBM Station].[Date Reported]) LEFT JOIN 
    [Gateway Status] ON [Node Status].[Date Verified] = [Gateway Status].Updated) ON Locations.LocationID = [Node Status].[Location Status]
WHERE 
    (((Nodes.[Node Serial Number])=[Enter node serial number]))
ORDER BY 
    [Node Status].[Date Verified] DESC
```